# How do I solve the following log equation?

Tags: logarithms

Solve:

$$x^x = \ln x + 1$$

There should be only one solution, $ x=1$, but I cannot prove it.

Comment: You can easily *verify* the $x = 1$ solution by just plugging it in.  Proving that there aren't any *other* solutions is a bit harder.

Comment: The derivative is monotone increasing and $x=1$ is a global min.

Comment: Can you want to improve your question? For example, what have you tried?

Comment: Use the well-known inequality: $e^x≥x+1$.

You have:

$$
\begin{align}\ln x+1=x^x=e^{x\ln x}&≥x\ln x+1\\
\ln x+1&≥x\ln x+1\\
\ln x &≥x\ln x\\
\ln x(x-1)&≤0.
\end{align}
$$

Now, you can complete the final step.

Comment: $f(x)=x^x$ is a convex function on $]0,+\infty[$ and $g(x)=\ln x+1$ is a concave function on $]0,+\infty[$. Since the curves $y=f(x)$ and $y=g(x)$ have the same tangent at the point $P(1,1)$ that is $y=x$, it follows that $P(1,1)$ is the only point of intersection of them, hence $x=1$ is the only solution of the equation $f(x)=g(x)$.